# How to get the value of drop down list in ajax in php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

How to get the value of drop down list in ajax in php?

**PHP code:**

```
<select name="Department" id="Department" class="DropDown">
 <?php

     $sql = "select * from department_details";
     $exec = mysql_query($sql);

     echo "<option  value='0'>Select</option>";                                            

     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($exec))
     {  
 ?>

   <?php echo "<option value=\"".$row['DepartmentId']."\">".$row['DepartmentName']."</option> \n  "; ?> 

<?php } ?>

     <option value="other">Other</option>
   </select>
```

**JavaScript Code:**

```
<script>

  $("#form").submit(function(event) {

  event.preventDefault();

  var $form = $( this ),
  value1 = $form.find( 'input[name="ProfessorName"]' ).val(),
  value2 = $form.find( 'input[name="Department"]' ).val(),

  url = $form.attr( 'action' );

  var posting = $.post( url, { ProfessorName: value1, Department: value2 } );

  posting.done(function( data ) {

  $( "#result" ).empty().append( data );
  });
  });
  </script>
```

How to get the value of department from the drop down list using ajax without page refresh.

Answer (score 3):

Using jquery you can try this

```
value2 = $("#Department").val();
```

Answer (score 3):

To get the select value, change :

```
value2 = $form.find( 'input[name="Department"]' ).val(),
```

To

```
value2 = $form.find( 'select[name="Department"]' ).val(),
```

And because you have an id on it, you can directly make

```
value2 = $form.find( '#Department' ).val(),
```

You used input selector, but Department is a select element.

Don't forget to make your function `return false;`, in order to prevent the form from being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

As you are using ajax, Use Jquery's [Serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

With this, you can create a text string (out of form field values) in standard URL-encoded notation, handy enough to make ajax calls.